# strange build time error in angular 5 app

Tags: angular, typescript, build, production

I am developing one application where I am getting object from http request and converting it to itteratable array like this. When I run the app in development mode the code sometime runs and give random error like below. But when I do run ng build --prod, it always gives me the below error and I am stuck due to it.

Where I have missed anything?

```
         Object.keys(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties']).forEach(inputKey => {
              this.newfdata[element]['properties'].push(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][inputKey]);

        }



       // this is line no. 223
                this.objectProps = Object.keys(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties']).map(prop => { 

          return Object.assign({}, { key: prop} , res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][prop]);

        // this is line no. 228
          });
```

I got the below error due to above lines.

```
ERROR in src/app/shared/layout/add.component.ts(223,5): error TS1005: ',' expected.
src/app/shared/layout/add.component.ts(228,11): error TS1005: ')' expected.
```

Please help me. Because of this issue whole app is not getting into prod mode.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error may be because of some other code you have written previously. Maybe you have a function that is not closed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You closed the forEach before closing of input key function , may be that is causing the error , change the line on top of line no.223 as i did below ,hope this will solve the issue.

```
 Object.keys(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties']).forEach(inputKey => {
          this.newfdata[element]['properties'].push(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][inputKey]

    }); // close forEach 



   // this is line no. 223
            this.objectProps = Object.keys(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties']).map(prop => { 

      return Object.assign({}, { key: prop} , res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][prop]);

    // this is line no. 228
      });
```

Comment: Yup It was the problem. Thanks for reaching out. The strange part is TS ignores this in development mode.